# NSIS: Switch between 3.X versions

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

I want to have my script compatible with `nsis-3.03` and `nsis-3.04`. I know this:

```
!if 0n1 > 0 ; >= 3.0b0 
!endif
```

But I don't understand why  `0n1 > 0` means `>= 3.0b0`?

I want to do something like

```
!if ... ; version=[3.0-3.3]
    ; do stuff
!else if  .., ; version > 3.3
    ; do other stuff
!else
     ; pass
!endif
```

I can`t use `${NSIS_PACKEDVERSION}`, because it is wrong build at debain based systems.

Comment: Which new feature of 3.04 do you actually want to use?

Comment: The ``IsNativeMachineArchitecture`` helper (see [Changelog](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Docs/AppendixF.html#v3.04)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!if 0n1 > 0 ; >= 3.0b0` works because older versions do not understand 0n1 and treats it as 0 so it just becomes `0 > 0` in older versions.

NSIS v3.04 and later forces NSIS_PACKEDVERSION to be a somewhat usable value even if nobody specifies a version when compiling.

To detect a specific feature implemented in a .NSH you can just check if the define or macro exists, there is no need to do a version check:

```
!include x64.nsh
!ifdef IsNativeMachineArchitecture
...
!else
...
!endif
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you maybe add this information to the documentation?

Comment: Sorry, forget it. I found it.

Comment: 0nXYZ is documented at the start of the pre-processor (Chapter 5)